# Are static classes bad practice in PHP?

Tags: php, static-classes

I would like to know what other people think about them.

(With "static classes" I mean a class whose all functions and variables are static).

I've found them very practical. I have this custom class for PDO that I accessed through $Db, and I had to "global $Db" on every function that had to make queries to the database.

I just found out about static classes and how they don't need to be globaled in functions. I made the PDO class a static class, removed all the "global $Db" from the functions that used it and call it like DB::function(), it works just like before, with no problems, and I won't have to "global $Db" from now on. I'm tempted to do the same with other classes I use often.

So I find it too nice to be a good thing. Or is it?

Comment: @Gordon shared a very interesting blog post on this a few days back: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html

Answer (score 0):

To do something similar in PHP you can use singletons static functions to run a single instance of an object for a class throughout all your code.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static $s_instance;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$s_instance)
        {
            self::$s_instance = new MyClass();
        }

        return self::$s_instance;
    }

    private function __construct(...) { ... }

    // All your non-static stuff

}
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @Pekka "I have this custom class for PDO that I accessed through $Db, and I had to "global $Db" on every function that had to make queries to the database.", "I just found out about static classes and how they don't need to be globaled in functions.". I'm offering a similar concept that fits into these descriptions since you can call getInstance from any functions to return the singleton object. It's also more recommendable then static classes.